# User Credentials Android. Who can read the web traffic?

Tags: certificates

Are User Credentials on Android such as "user key", "user certificate", and "CA certificate" only used to connect to a single specific network?

In other words, will the network admins be able to see my web traffic if i'm using cellular data and or a different WiFi network that doesn't use those certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are User Credentials on Android such as "user key", "user certificate", and "CA certificate" only used to connect to a single specific network?

A `user certificate` is used to authenticate a user against an HTTPS website and is totally agnostic of the network used to access this website.

A `CA Certificate` is used to ensure that the certificate provided by an HTTPS server has been signed by a legitimate authority and is also totally network-agnostic.

> In other words, will the network admins be able to see my web traffic if i'm using cellular data and or a different WiFi network that doesn't use those certificates?

As said previously, a `CA certificate` is used system-wide.

So let's say that:

- Your boss requested you to install the `CA certificate` Toto.pem.
- Your boss is able to run a MITM attack between your device (regardless the network used) and an HTTPS website you're visiting.

Then your boss just have to build a certificate for the website you're visiting and sign it with the `CA certificate` that he made you install on your device.
The connection will be reported as "secured" most of the time in basic HTTPS server setup. (exception are if more clever methods are used by the targeted website, such as HTTPS pinning, etc...)

Comment: Would using a VPN prevent them from viewing traffic?

Comment: Using a VPN secure the transport layer between your device and the VPN gateway.  Depending on where in the chain is located the attacker, it maybe enought or not ...

Comment: There is some helpful info here, but I don't think this answers the main question asked.  Yes, if the company is able to MITM the traffic and has a root CA installed, they will be able to monitor all traffic.  However, that isn't the question.  The question is **if** the company can MITM all traffic if the OP is connected to a different network.

Comment: @ConorMancone and there's no answer to this "broad" question: the source network isn't relevant if company have hands on something further (destination server, etc...)  That's why i gave OP some clarifications regarding what is a CA, a user certificate, etc... OP was mixing topic that, even if related, weren't totally the same.